# derivative of error function

Tags: derivatives, error-function

How can I calculate the derivatives

$$\frac{\partial \mbox{erf}\left(\frac{\ln(t)-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)}{\partial \mu}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial \mbox{erf}\left(\frac{\ln(t)-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)}{\partial \sigma}$$

where $\mbox{erf}$ denotes the error function can be given by $$\mbox{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x}\exp(-t^2)\,dt$$

I have tried it using [WA derivative calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/calculators/derivative-calculator/) but I am not able to understand the steps.

Comment: The error function erf($x$) is just $\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\ dt$, so its derivative is just $\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}$. All you have to do for your examples is use the chain rule.

Answer (score 5):

You have error in your definition of error function :-).
The definition of error function is
$$\operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt = \int_0^x \frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt.$$
Derivative of this integral with variable is it's integrand applied to upper boundary and multiplicated by boundary's derivative. ($\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$)
$$\frac{\partial \operatorname{erf}(x) }{\partial x}=1\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2}$$

The next step is calculating derivative of a composite function. I hope you can do it yourself.

==Added==

You should treat $t$ and $\mu$ as a parameters. For example: $$\frac{\partial \frac{\ln(t)-\mu}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}}{\partial \sigma}=\frac{\ln(t)-\mu}{\sqrt{2}}{\ln|\sigma|}$$ Continue it.

Comment: Thanks Georgy Dunaev It was a typographical error, I have corrected it.

Comment: I do not have to integrate with respect to x but with respect to mu and sigma

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell it our for the derivative w.r.t. $\mu$:
$$\Phi(\mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{2}[1+erf(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}})]$$
$$\Phi(\mu,\sigma^2) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}} e^{-t^2} dt$$
$$\frac{\Phi(\mu,\sigma^2)}{d\mu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}  e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma})$$
$$\frac{\Phi(\mu,\sigma^2)}{d\mu} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma}  e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} = - \phi(\mu,\sigma^2)$$
Same thing w.r.t. $\sigma$:
$$\frac{\Phi(\mu,\sigma^2)}{d\sigma} = \frac{\mu-x}{\sqrt{2 \pi}\sigma^2}  e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} =  \phi(\mu,\sigma^2) \frac{\mu-x}{\sigma}$$