# Error Function Differentiating

Tags: error-function

$$\mathrm{erf}(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-x}^xe^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt$$

How would one go about differentiating this function?
I have tried this method:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(e^{-x^2} - e ^{-(-x^2)}\right) = 0$$

This doesn't seem like the right answer but I don't know how else to go about it. Any help?

Comment: $e^{-t^2}\Big|_{t = -x} = e^{-x^2}$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [derivative of error function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755149/derivative-of-error-function)

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle\textrm{erf}(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt$, $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(\text{erf}(x))=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}$.

Alternatively, $\displaystyle\textrm{erf}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{-x}e^{-t^2}dt$, so

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}(\text{erf}(x))&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{d}{d(-x)}\left(\int_0^{-x}e^{-t^2}dt\right)\frac{d(-x)}{dx}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-(-x)^2}(-1)\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: Did the normalizations on the two definitions get flipped? I'd think the former would be $1/\sqrt\pi$ and the latter $2/\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: @zahbaz I forgot to change the lower limit of the integral after copy-and-paste. It should be $0$ instead of $-x$.

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, consider
$$F(x)=\int_{-x}^x f(t)\, dt$$ and use the fundamental theorem of calculus
$$F'(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$$ Similarly,
$$G(x)=\int_{-x}^x f(t^2)\, dt\implies G'(x)=2f(x^2)$$
$$H(x)=\int_{-x}^x f(t^3)\, dt\implies H'(x)=f(x^3)+f(-x^3)$$
$$I(x)=\int_{-x}^x f(t^4)\, dt\implies I'(x)=2f(x^4)$$